# intellij/android studio idea shows a balloon of preview of a code statement

Tags: intellij-idea

i am using `android studio/intellij idea`
my idea starts showing me a balloon with a preview of a method
and it disturbs me when i need the top bar like finding text
(it appears when i scroll far from that part of code).
i tried to search the web and to play with the settings
but i did not find any solution for it how do i fix it?

[image: my problem]

Answer (score 1):

Disable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Appearance | **Show code lens on scrollbar hover**.

- [Related documentation section](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2021.2/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#lens_mode_code).

Comment: I don't think It's the same feature - the author probably has the same problem as me, that is code lens showing without pointer going anywhere near scrollbar. And it shows up when you scroll away from (not using scrollbar) from that piece of code