# Android studio - chromeless dialog in the editor with 4 code lines

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 2020.03 Patch 4, 
shows 4 lines of code in a chromeless dialog, 
when I am scrolling through the editor.

I do not understand, how it picks those 4 lines.
I do not understand, how this dialog should be useful to me.

How do I disable those dialogs?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a Code lens that is shown when you hover on the scroll bar of the editor.

To disable that, there are two ways:

1. Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Uncheck Show code leans on scrollbar hover and save it.
2. Right click on the Scrollbar and Uncheck Show code leans on scrollbar hover.

This will disable the code lens but it may not solve your problem as mentioned by a few users in other similar questions, for example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69439517/8244632).